# Compiling into files whose names are different than the project name in MSVS (2005+)

Tags: project-settings

I was wondering:
If I am using MSVS2005 or later and wish to compile my project into a file (exe, dll, lib, etc) whose name is different than the project name, what should I do? Where is this setting? I couldn't seem to find this setting anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look in the Project Properties? Also, what language are you using? VB.NET? C++?

Comment: C++. I looked around, but didn't see anything, only a field for changing the names of the object files.

Answer (score 0):

It is different for different types of projects. I can tell you that for C# (and, most likely, VB.NET as well), it's in project properties (right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, choose *Properties*), tab *Application*, field *Assembly Name* (the very first one).